# Angular, UI grid, detect the end of horizontal scrollbar

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, scroll, grid

I'm using Angular UI grid with horizontal scrolling.

I'd like to detect the event when the maximum left scrolling is reached. Is possible to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome. It might be worth posting what you have tried and researched so far in this regard. It helps people respond more accurately and appropriately.

Comment: In ui-grid I didn't find anything property to do so. I saw that is possibile to detect the and of a scrolling in a way such this http://jsfiddle.net/cNmhR/24/, but I'd like to know if exists a way that uses only angular components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollLeft method of jquery to find the scroll position inside any element. Follow below link for more details:

https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the scroll event on the window. Measure your variables and act accordingly.

```
  //Brings slider into place with scrolled ad_unit list.
  var lastPos = $scope.scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $scope.scrollContainer.scrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();

    if(lastPos < $scope.scrollContainer.scrollLeft) {
      loadCreatives();
    }
    if(lastPos > $scope.scrollContainer.scrollLeft) {
      _this.refreshSlider();
    }

    lastPos = $scope.scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
  });
```